# add WordPress script to page conditionally by category

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I use a plugin "Post Tags and Categories for Pages" which adds categories to pages.

My intention is to enqueue an external script on a page, only when it's needed. So if I assign a page to a category, only that page gets the script loaded.

I have this hook:

```
to function my_conditional_enqueue_script1() {
    global $page;
    if ( is_single() && in_category( '19' ) ) { 
    wp_enqueue_script( '/members/application/cart/views/public/js/cart.js' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_conditional_enqueue_script1');
```

Seems like it should work, but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Or, is it more advisable to maybe add the script on a page my using short-codes (wrap the hook in plugin somehow)?

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_single()` doesn't work for the `page` post type, use `is_page()` instead.

You're also missing the first argument for `wp_enqueue_script`, the script handle. Source should be the second argument.

```
function my_conditional_enqueue_script1() {
    if ( is_page() && in_category( 19 ) ) { 
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'my-cart-script',
            '/members/application/cart/views/public/js/cart.js'
        );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_conditional_enqueue_script1');
```

Comment: Tested and it's works perfectly. I'm still leaning. Thank you very much.